# A word/characteristic for "all bark and no bite"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word or a characteristic to describe someone that is "All bark and no bite"?

*Describes someone who often says cutting remarks, but actually has a soft personality underneath.*

> Its okay, I know that Danny is a little mean, but he's **all bark and no bite.**

Comment: I've retagged this correctly (you need the `-request` tags when looking for something). Please take a moment to review the detailed tag info: the [single-word-request tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) has a lot of requirements which are relevant to all such requests, including phrases and idioms.

Comment: Is this good enough for the tag?

Comment: Danny is a *sheep in wolf's clothing*.

Answer (score 1):

Danny is **[harmless](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/harmless)**.

From vocabulary.com:

> ... If your friend is scared of dogs, you can reassure her by saying, "Sure, he's 150 pounds and has a loud bark, but Fido is harmless!" Things that are safe or benign don't cause harm, and are therefore harmless, like your dad's harmless teasing or a compostable paper plate that's harmless to the environment.

The word is used in the sense you mean often enough, but it only works when the *all bark* part is already established, which is preferably just before the remark.

Answer (score 0):

> Its okay, I know that Danny is a little mean, but he's also
>   **spineless**.

[M-W dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spineless)